# Emacs 24.3 for windows, Cedet can not work with ECB, error: Recursive `require' for feature `speedbar'

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-ecb

Currently I'm struggling with the **windows' Emacs (emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip form http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/)**. After I installed the **ECB (version- 20130202.1459)** via package-intall-package ecb through **MELPA** site, and added 
(require 'ecb) in ".emacs" file, running the emacs leads to the following error:

**error: Recursive `require' for feature`speedbar'**

When I start Emacs with the `--debug-init' option to check error backtrace, I got following message:

ECB 2.40 uses CEDET 2.0 (contains semantic 2.2, eieio 1.4, speedbar ).
require: Autoloading failed to define function debug

Can any people know what's wrong with that and how to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any other package loaded before this command?

Comment: Can you also try to install newer version of ECB?

Comment: Except Emacs build-in packages I only use two Cedet and Ecb. However I find a solution, that is, instead of putting Cedet and Ecb in the build-in location ".emacs.d\elpa" or "site-lisp", I put them in an custom folder say "external" somewhere, it works. Problem is now solved, but I'm not quite sure if it is caused by that functions in buil-in location will be called recursively somehow?

Comment: there is some problem when external & Emacs's internal CEDETs are used together - that's why external should be loaded before internal